# Iframe embedded content not loading

Tags: html, http

I am using an `<iframe>` HTML tag on my page e.g. to embed content from YouTube:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DnPQNOq8x2s"></iframe>
```

However the content is not loaded.

In Firefox nothing is shown. In Chrome, a message like "Request blocked by an extension" is shown.

*What is blocking the embedded iframe content and how can I get it to load and be shown?*

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) HTTP response header.

If your HTTP framework or server is configured to insert this header into the response, you should make sure that you set the [`frame-src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-src) directive for it:

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-src *.youtube.com;` (or equivalent for any site you want to embed)

The documentation for your HTTP server or framework should specify how to configure this.